# anonymous authentication spring 403

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

Hey there (thanks for reading ;)

I had this extremely annoying situation:

First of all I wanted to apply security to our spring application,
I was very happy to get a 403 so the next day I wanted to actually authorise people to the application.

That seemed harder to do then anticipated :(

After some work on preauthorisation it was decided that our application didn't need explicit spring security (because we had other authentication) so we opted for Anonymous authentication,

I followed the guide from [spring-security-master](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples) for preauthentication and adapted it following the specs on [the reference page for anonymous authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/anonymous.html) to no vail.

(I still got an error code 403)

My applicationContext-security.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

        <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
            <sec:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
                <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="anonymousAuthFilter"/>
            </sec:filter-chain-map>
        </bean>

        <bean id="anonymousAuthFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
            <constructor-arg value="foobar"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
            <constructor-arg value="foobar"/>
        </bean> 

        <bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
                <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
                <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager"/>
                <property name="securityMetadataSource">
                    <sec:filter-security-metadata-source>
                        <sec:intercept-url pattern='/index.jsp' access='ROLE_ANONYMOUS'/>
                        <sec:intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_ANONYMOUS'/>
                    </sec:filter-security-metadata-source>
                </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
            <constructor-arg>
                <list>
                    <ref bean="roleVoter"/>
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="true"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter"/>

        <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <sec:authentication-provider ref="anonymousAuthenticationProvider" />
        </sec:authentication-manager>

    </beans>
```

My web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <security-role>
            <role-name>ROLE_USER</role-name>
        </security-role>
        <security-role>
            <role-name>ROLE_SUPERVISOR</role-name>
        </security-role>
        <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>All areas</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>ROLE_USER</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>

    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be that:

```
        <security-role>
            <role-name>ROLE_USER</role-name>
        </security-role>
        <security-role>
            <role-name>ROLE_SUPERVISOR</role-name>
        </security-role>
        <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>All areas</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>ROLE_USER</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
```

was defined;

when I removed this the anonymous authorisation worked.

(I found out about this just before I was going to post the question)

Hope this helps anyone,

S.